# unity come back to default

Tags: unity, default

I did some changes via compiz, the result was this:

[image]

As you see just time color is default and other like wireless and volume's color are dark. What is the terminal command to tell unity, come back to your default?

Comment: It looks like you chose a non-default icon theme. I don't know the terminal command to change this, but you can install unity-tweak-tool and change the icon theme back to the default, which is ubuntu-dark-mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your only problem, you just need to change the icon theme  you can use `unity-tweak-tool`).

If you really need to reset unity, there are a couple of tools to do it, you can find more info here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html